# C# Export Telerik radGrid to excel got error the file could be corrupted

Tags: c#, excel, telerik-grid

I am doing an APP in aspx, I am using telerik:radgrid and also I have a botton to export to excel.
Here is the definition of my telerik:radgrid

```
<telerik:radgrid onprerender="ItemsGrid_PreRender" onpageindexchanged="ItemsGrid_PageIndexChanged"
            skinid="FilmTrackPOListPagingGrid" id="ItemsGrid" ondeletecommand="ItemsGrid_DeleteCommand"
            allowfilteringbycolumn="True" datasourceid="PoDataSource" onitemcommand="ItemsGrid_ItemCommand"
            allowpaging="True" allowsorting="True" runat="server" showgrouppanel="false"
            AllowMultiRowSelection="true"
            pagesize="5">
```

inside my  radGrid i have this

```
<MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="Id" CommandItemDisplay="top" DataKeyNames="Id">
   
<CommandItemTemplate>
                
            </CommandItemTemplate>

                <NoRecordsTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 5px;">
                        There are no purchase orders that meet the filter critera.</div>
                </NoRecordsTemplate>

                <SortExpressions>
                    <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="PONumber" SortOrder="Descending" />
                </SortExpressions>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" />
                    
                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn HeaderText="Select" UniqueName="SelectRow" >
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px"/>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                    </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn> 
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="EditColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="60px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="EditColumnLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# UIUtility.ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/Pages/PurchaseOrder.aspx?{0}={1}", "pid",  DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "Id" ))) %>'
                                ToolTip="Edit P.O.">
                                <InvenTrackControls:SkinImage ID="EditImage" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/buttons/grid_edit.png" BorderWidth="0" />
                            </asp:HyperLink>


                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CopyButton" runat="server" CommandName="ItemsGrid_CopyCommand" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/buttons/icon_copy_16.png"
                            OnClientClick="return ConfirmPurchaseOrderCopy();" ToolTip="Copy P.O." ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" BorderWidth="0" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="EditColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="30px"
                                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="30px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/buttons/grid_delete.png"
                                    OnClientClick="return ConfirmPurchaseOrderDeletion();" ToolTip="Delete P.O." ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>                        

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="PONumber" DataField="PONumber" HeaderText="P.O. #" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Projects" DataField="Projects" HeaderText="Project(s)" FilterControlWidth="88%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="200px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="200px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CustomVendorBlock" DataField="CustomVendorGridBlock" HeaderText="Vendor" FilterControlWidth="88%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="225px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
                        ItemStyle-Width="225px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CustomShipToBlock" DataField="CustomShipToGridBlock" HeaderText="Ship To" FilterControlWidth="88%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="225px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
                        ItemStyle-Width="225px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="POTotal"  HeaderText="P.O. Total" DataField="Total" FilterControlWidth="68%"  DataType="System.Decimal"  DataFormatString="{0:C}" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="EqualTo" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="90px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                        ItemStyle-Width="90px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CreateUser" DataField="CreateUser" HeaderText="Created By" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />

                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn UniqueName="CreateDate" DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="Date Created" FilterControlWidth="78%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="EqualTo" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />


                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn  UniqueName="OrderDate" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date Ordered" FilterControlWidth="78%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="EqualTo" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />

                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn  UniqueName="RequiredDate" DataField="RequiredDate" HeaderText="Date Required" FilterControlWidth="78%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="EqualTo" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />


                    <filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status" DataField="Status"
                        HeaderText="Status" AllowFiltering="true" FilterControlWidth="100%" FilterDataSourceId="PoStatusDataSource"
                        FilterDataTextField="Status" FilterDataValueField="Status"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="115px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Status" runat="server" DataSourceID="PoStatusDataSource"
                                DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Status" Width="115px" DropDownWidth="130px"
                                Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>' SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>'>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn>

                    <filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="CurrencyISOCode" UniqueName="CurrencyISOCode" DataField="CurrencyISOCode"
                        HeaderText="Currency" AllowFiltering="true" FilterControlWidth="100%" FilterDataSourceId="CurrencyDataSource"
                        FilterDataTextField="ISOCode" FilterDataValueField="ISOCode"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="CurrencyValue" runat="server" Width="115px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CurrencyISOCode") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="CurrencyEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="CurrencyDataSource"
                                DataTextField="ISOCode" DataValueField="ISOCode" Width="115px" DropDownWidth="130px"
                                Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CurrencyISOCode") %>' SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CurrencyISOCode") %>'>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn>

                    <filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="ShippingMethod" UniqueName="ShippingMethod" DataField="ShippingMethod"
                        HeaderText="Shipping Method" AllowFiltering="true" FilterControlWidth="100%" FilterDataSourceId="ShippingMethodDataSource"
                        FilterDataTextField="Name" FilterDataValueField="Name"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Width="115px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShippingMethod") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ShippingMethodEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="ShippingMethodDataSource"
                                DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="115px" DropDownWidth="130px"
                                Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShippingMethod") %>' SelectedValue='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShippingMethod") %>'>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </filmtrack:RadComboBoxFilterableTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ShippingAccount" DataField="ShippingAccountNumber" HeaderText="Shipping Account #" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="AirwayBillNumber" DataField="AirwayBillNumber" HeaderText="Airway Bill #" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="125px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Terms" DataField="Terms" HeaderText="Terms" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="300px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="300px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SpecialInstructions" DataField="SpecialInstructions" HeaderText="Special Instructions" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="300px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="300px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="GeneralPurchaseOrderNote" DataField="GeneralPurchaseOrderNote" HeaderText="General P.O. Note" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="300px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="300px" />

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SupportCode" DataField="SupportCode" HeaderText="Support #" FilterControlWidth="68%" 
                        CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
```

My export button is like this

```
  protected void ExportListToExcelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["GridPageSize"] = ItemsGrid.PageSize;
        ItemsGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
        ItemsGrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        ItemsGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = false;
        ItemsGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "PurchaseOrderList";
        ItemsGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
    }
```

The migration works fine.. But i am facing a problem ...

When I open the excel, it says that the file is corrupt.

[image: Error on Excel]

Where that error came from?

Comment: There are multiple questions in your question. Please ask a single question at a time.

Comment: I just added one question... Thanks

Comment: Diego, was about to start writing an answer, but ShaniaGhafur009 has a correct one already. Basically the export is an HTML that Excel can parse, but it is hardening its security. So, it is recommended to use the `ExportToXlsx` method, which should also generate an .xlsx file.